# How to compare the items in a lists of lists with the items in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I want to compare the items in a list of lists `a` , to the items on a list `x`. The idea is to do this comparison item by item, based on a condition, and then perform some action based on whether the condition is met or not. However, the idea I have to iterate over the items does not work. Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
x = [10, 11, 12]
a = [[11, 10, 12], [12, 15, 20], [11, 14, 16]]

for i, j in a, b: # I am looking for an alternative way to do this
    counter = []
    if i <= j: # if the item in a is equal to or smaller than the corresponding
               # item in list x, then the list is rejected and the counter is
               # increased by 1
        counter =+ 1
    else:
        print(counter, np.mean(a[-1])) # print the number of rejected lists
```

The result I am expecting is:

`1` In list 1 in `a`, the 2nd item is smaller than and the 3rd item equal to the 2nd and 3rd items in `x`.

`18` The other two lists do not meet the condition and hence are okay, and the average of their last items is (20 + 16)/ 2 = 18

Comment: Please let me know why the question is downvoted, so I can post better questions next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to convert the arrays to numpy arrays, you can exploit element-wise comparison in order to avoid having to iterate at all:

```
x = np.array(x)
a = np.array(a)

# numpy arrays allow the use of element-wise comparison
logic = x <= a
print("logic selection matrix:")
print(logic)

# flag entries that don't fully meet the conditions as dictated by the logic matrix
flags = np.sum(logic,axis=1) != 3

# counter of false entries
c = np.sum(flags)
print (f"final value of counter is {c}")

mean = np.mean(a[flags == False][:,-1])
print (f"found mean of entries is {mean}")
```

output:

```
logic selection matrix:
[[ True False  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
final value of counter is 1
found mean of entries is 18.0
```

Although if you need to perform more complex operations other than adding to a counter this will be harder to implement. You can also partially use this property while keeping the if-else structure:

```
x = [10, 11, 12]
a = [[11, 10, 12], [12, 15, 20], [11, 14, 16]]

x = np.array(x)
a = np.array(a)

lastitems = []
for lst in a:
    if np.all(x <= lst):
        lastitems.append(lst[-1])
    else:
        c = np.sum(x <= lst)
        print(f"found {c} entries smaller than x array in list")
        
print(f"list of last_items: {lastitems}")
mean = np.mean(lastitems)
print(f"mean of last items: {mean}")
```

Output:

```
found 2 entries smaller than x array in list
list of last_items: [20, 16]
mean of last items: 18.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a nice solution. The second solution is most useful in my case. I only think that the condition in the 'if' clause should be ```if np.all(x < lst):``` in my case, not ```<=```. In the else case, I would need a counter. But that is easy to add.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
x = [10, 11, 12]
a = [[11, 10, 12], [12, 15, 20], [11, 14, 16]]

valid = []
for index, i in enumerate(a):
    for j in range(0, len(x)):
        if i[j] <= x[j]:
            print((index +1), '. In list ', str(index +1),  ', Item ', str(j+1), ' is smaller than item ', str(j+1), ' in x')
            break
        else:
            if(j == len(x) - 1):
                print((index +1), '. List ', str(index +1),  ' is ok ')
                valid.append( i[-1])
print('================')
print('Average = ', np.mean(valid)) # print the number of lists
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice solution. It works. The print statements show exactly where the condition is violated. I only need a counter for counting either the approved or the non-approved lists. But that is easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks. You can mark it as answer if it solved your problem.